# Как удалить элемент из контейнера?

Tags: c++, stl, std-list

Есть класс `Student` и список `list<Student> Lst`, список `STL`. Пытаюсь с помощью функции-члена remove() удалить нужный мне элемент, но пишет 10 ошибок, почему не могу понять, смотрел документацию STL там только описание функции remove() - для чего она, но я и так знаю? для чего она, как его удалить не пойму. Код программы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
    private:

    char Name[50];
    double Bal;
    int Curs;

    public:

    Student(){}
    ~Student (){}
    void Set(char name[], double bal, int curs) {strcpy(Name, name); Bal = bal; Curs = curs;}

    double GetBal()const{return Bal;}
    int GetCurs()const{return Curs;}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Student &obj);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Student &obj)
{
    out<<"\n";        
    out<<"Имя: "<<obj.Name<<endl;        
    out<<"Бал: "<<obj.Bal<<endl;        
    out<<"Курс: "<<obj.Curs<<endl;        
    out<<"\n";

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");

    char name[50];
    double bal;
    int curs;

    Student Spisok[50];
    int i = 0;
    list<Student> LST;

    bool exit = false;

    while(!exit)
    {
        cout<<"Введите имя: \n";
        cin.getline(name, 50);

        cout<<"Средний бал студента: \n";
        cin>>bal;

        cout<<"Курс: \n";
        cin>>curs;

        Spisok[i].Set(name, bal, curs);
        LST.push_back(Spisok[i]);

        cout<<"Выход? (1/0)\n";
        cin>>exit;
        cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        i++;
    }

    cout<<"DO\n";

    for(list<Student>::const_iterator ci = LST.begin(); ci!=LST.end(); ci++)
    cout<<*ci<<endl;

    cout<<"Posle\n";

    for(list<Student>::const_iterator ci = LST.begin(); ci!=LST.end(); ci++)
    {
        if((*ci).GetBal() == 5 && (*ci).GetCurs()== 1)
        LST.remove((*ci));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибки появляются, потому что Вы используете константный итератор.